# Locate LAS Points By Proximity gives ERROR 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, lidar, proximity, error-999999

I am trying to locate LAS points which is within a specific distance (25cm or 50cm) from the 3D points in a feature class. This is exactly what the `Locate LAS Points By Proximity` tool should do. My problem is just that I get a 999999-error, and I have no clue why.

My input files are a Las Dataset and a 3D point feature class and I have tried a lot of combinations of settings and outputs, but with the same error message every time.

I can only drag-and-drop my point feature class into the tool - if I browse to find it in the windows folder, then it is not visible. Maybe that can be a hint for solving the issue.

[image: Tool inputs (I also tried without changing class codes and calculating statistics but again with error)]

[image: Message in geoprocessing result]

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error but was able to resolve it by applying the Add Z Information tool to the proximity dataset which added a Z field to the attribute table.  Note the proximity dataset must be a Z-enabled feature class.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the tool `Make Feature Layer` first. There you should be able to create a layer that can be used as input to geoprocessing tools that accepts feature layer as input.

Another option is to use ArcPy, where your code could be something like:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('3D')
env.workspace = 'C:/test'
arcpy.LocateLasPointsByProximity_3d('Proximity_test.lasd','GCP_test.shp', 
                                    search_radius="50 Centimeters", 
                                    count_field="LAS_count",
                                    out_features="Test_result.shp"
                                    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the Make Feature Layer, but it results in the same error.. and I am not used to work with ArcPy so I'd rather solve it with the tool if possible.